# Is there an mix phx option to use yarn instead of npm?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, yarnpkg

npm is usually several times slower than yarn, which is why Rails uses it instead. Is there also an option for Phoenix tasks to use it instead of npm? If no, I'll consider a PR.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no".

[The slightly longer explanation is here.](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/pull/1963#issuecomment-396079993)

Comment: That's good to know but it doesn't solve the problems of compiling and live-reloading picking up yarn. I'll probably end up forking phoenix since npm is so damn slow.